# Prevent HTML Injection in Codeigniter Input class

Tags: codeigniter, html-injections

As we all know `$this->input->post('$myvariable',TRUE)` is XSS filtered. But is there any way i can prevent HTML Injection in the same.I read few articles but none of them give clear idea from where to start.Any Help ?

Comment: this will block all the code injeqtion

Comment: Abdulla bro.One of my search is using  `$this->input->post('$myvariable',TRUE)`.Our security expert says it is vulnerable to html injection.

Comment: If you are about to submit input fields then you can add rule at the time of form validation....
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
Here xss_clean will filter the data and prevent them to submit form data!!So No space of html injection.

Comment: html_escape() works. In forms we can use form_prep() which again uses html_escape().Form helper doesnot include html_escape().So to prevent html injection use html_escape with input class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->input->post('variable',TRUE);
```

When you add TRUE it will filter all your Injections (SQL, XSS).
 As well as load this `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` in `application/config`

> Info : The Input class has the ability to filter input **automatically to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.**

---

And you can use

```
html_escape()
```

> Info : This function provides short cut for `htmlspecialchars()` function. It accepts string and array. To **prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS), it is very useful**.

and this

```
remove_invisible_characters()
```

> Info : This function **prevents inserting null characters between ascii characters, like Java\0script**.